# My session auto destroyed after query from signup table

Tags: php, mysql, session

My user registration table name is "signup". I have many table. But when I query from "signup" table then my session automatically destroyed. But another table has no problem. How can i overcome from this problem? Here is my code

```
 $id=$_GET['id'];
                     $sql="SELECT * FROM signup WHERE id='$id'";                        
                    $result=mysql_query($sql);
                     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    if ($row['new_khatian']==1) {$new_khatian="checked";} 
                    echo $new_khatian;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see where have you put the session_destroy() function.The above code doesn't have anything to do with the session i think.

Comment: This is sign out page. There are no problem and no link with query page. session_start();
unset($_SESSION["email"]); 
header("Location: login_door.php");